# how to pass the parameter in function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

how to pass the value of textbox  this is working for first select box and why not for all.if i check the check box the text box value will set to null

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch'.$i.'" class="onoffswitch'.$i.'-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch'.$i.'" checked onclick=my(this.form,'buy".$p."','sell".$p."','onoffswitch".$i."');>
 echo '<td><input type=text maxlength="6" size="6" value='.$cfet['purchaseprice'].' name=buy'.$p.'></td>'; 
 echo '<td><input type=text maxlength="6" size="6" value='.$cfet['sellingprice'].' name=sell'.$p.'></td>';
 function my(a,buy,sell,select)
 {
 alert("select"+select);
 alert("si"+a.select.checked);
 if(a.select..checked == false) {
 alert("true"+buy);
 a.buy.value="";
 a.sell.value="";
}
```

Comment: is your first line generated by echo too?

Comment: You're already passing the value, it's the first argument? It seems like the other arguments are syntax errors, looks like unquoted strings, but who knows ?

Comment: ya my 1st line generated in echo.

Comment: The value of which text input? There are two. Where is your attempt?

Comment: why is there no echo in the first line if it is generated by `echo`?

Comment: I would personally put the inputs in a form, and use POST handling if you want to use php. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript (and JQuery) you can pass values simply by including a variable in the name of the function and referencing like normal ie.

```
my(this.val,$,$,"x")

function my(value,something,somethingElse,letter){
var answer = somthing + somethingElse;
alert(value);
}
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_functions.asp

Comment: I would personally put the inputs in a form, and use POST handling if you want to use php. Read more here: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp

Answer (score 0):

The PHP code incorrect, please use `<?php /*code*/ ?>`

HTML with PHP code

```
 <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch<?php echo $i ?>" 
             class="onoffswitch<?php echo $i ?>-checkbox"
             id="myonoffswitch<?php echo $i; ?>" checked 
             onclick="my(this.value,'buy<?php echo $p ?>','sell<?php echo $p ?>');">
```

`PHP` echo

```
<?php 
    echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"onoffswitch$i\" 
                 class=\"onoffswitch$i-checkbox\"
                 id=\"myonoffswitch$i\" checked 
                 onclick=\"my(this.value,'buy$p','sell$p')\">";
```

Answer (score 0):

You asked  *how to pass the value of textbox as parameter*

you have to pass it like this:

```
onclick="my(this.value,"'.$cfet['purchaseprice'].'","'.$cfet['sellingprice']");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can get the values of the `input`s using jQuery. This is assuming that your checkbox is the current context (which in the case above, it is):

```
onclick="my(this.value, $(this).next().val(), $(this).nextAll().eq(1).val())"
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tDTk7/3/)

This could be made much more readable and easier to maintain if you used jQuery to attach the event handling functions:

```
$('#myonoffswitch').on('click', function(){
    var a = this.value, b = $(this).next().val(), c = $(this).nextAll().eq(1).val();
    alert(a + ' ' + b + ' ' + c);
});
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/tDTk7/2/)